# Nodejs module "worker_threads" returning error "Error: The V8 platform used by this instance of Node does not support creating Workers"

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm creating an app where I need to stop some code without doing all the buggy sleep forever methods, or creating an if statement in every function checking if the stop variable is true, so I decided to use worker_threads, but every time I use it, I get an error:

> Error: The V8 platform used by this instance of Node does not support creating Workers

And I don't understand why. Is it because it's inside Electron, maybe?

Code:

```
const { Worker } = require("worker_threads");
const test = new Worker('./Test.js')
```

Comment: Well, what version of the V8 platform do you have in your electron environment?  worker threads is a fairly recent addition (still tagged as experimental).  It was added in nodejs v10.5.0.

Comment: It might be more useful for you to post a new question that shows the actual problem you have and we could probably help you write proper asynchronous code that doesn't need `sleep()` or threads.

Comment: @jfriend00 have done that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56985003/how-to-stop-async-code-from-running-node-js) but the answers I got was all very(in my opion) too complicated to impement, for example having an if statement in EVERY function that check if the stop variable is true. Their must be a simple way to stop all code from executing in for example a javascript class without using workers. (I would like to use workers but the module "tiny-worker" takes 1 second to create a worker.(too much)

Comment: I've commented on that other question.  You're asking about [XY problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you ask about problems with with your attempted solution (sometimes misguided solution) rather than explaining the actual core problem with real code.  That makes it really hard for us to help you.

Comment: Bizarre how much time has passed and yet there isn't a real solution posted for this. The link provided by Sam H is behind a pay-wall, so I can't really see what that covers.