# The V8 platform used by this instance of Node does not support creating Workers

Tags: node.js, electron

With my current project I run into the following error message when creating a worker:

> ERROR Error: The V8 platform used by this instance
> of Node does not support creating Workers

I found a variety of posts here on SO with comments like these: [It was added in nodejs v10.5.0.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57013013/nodejs-module-worker-threads-returning-error-error-the-v8-platform-used-by-t)

Does anyone know whats going on?

```
$ process.versions
ares:'1.16.0'
brotli:'1.0.7'
chrome:'85.0.4183.39'
electron:'10.0.0-beta.14'
http_parser:'2.9.3'
icu:'67.1'
llhttp:'2.0.4'
modules:'82'
napi:'5'
nghttp2:'1.41.0'
node:'12.16.3'
openssl:'1.1.0'
unicode:'13.0'
```

**main.ts**

```
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegrationInWorker: true,
      nodeIntegration: true,
      allowRunningInsecureContent: (serve) ? true : false,
    },
  });
```

Comment: The error sounds pretty self-explanatory.  The implementation of nodejs baked into your version of electron does not support worker threads for the back-end code.  FYI, the chromium-based engine for the UI facing Javascript does apparently support web workers.  Further discussion here: [How to run background worker processes in Electron app](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-run-background-worker-processes-in-an-electron-app-e0dc310a93cc).

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this?

Comment: @jfriend00 looks like there's a paywall there and I get a message about the note being referenced having been deleted. It'd be so nice to have more help on this topic.

Comment: @JamesTSnell - The article is still there for me.  That site seems to only give you so many visits before it tries to sell you something.  If you visit there in a new clean browser or perhaps in incognito mode, you should be able to view it.  I don't have another relevant reference to replace it with.

Answer (score 1):

Launch Workers from main.js

I had my Workers launching from my renderer.js and then I noticed a comment here (https://www.giters.com/nrkno/sofie-atem-connection/issues/125) that mentioned there's a bug that results in this V8 platform message when Workers are kicked-off outside of main.js.

In my particular case, it's not working fully yet, but I don't get this message any more and I think my outstanding problems are unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error when I tried to use the worker pool in electron. I solved it by adding the `{workertype: 'process'}` when I create the worker pool as follows.

```
const pool = workerpool.pool('',  { workerType: 'process' });
```